# "functions are not valid as react child" when returning React.createElement in functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, higher-order-functions

I have a modal functional component

```
const Modal = ({component, newCompProps, otherStuff}) => {


 const modalBody = () => {
        return(
          <div>{React.createElement(component, newCompProps}</div>
         )
      }

  return(
     <div>{modalBody}</div>
  )

 }

  export default Modal
```

and I keep getting this error

`Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it..`

Theres some other stuff in the functional component too, but I only added above what matters.... how else can I return the new created element? I am using hooks as well.